# I want to use stripslash in php when writing a txt file

Tags: php, forms

I have a php file that receives data from a form and then writes that information to a txt file.  It works great except sometimes users use " or ' when filling in the fields.  When this happens the txt file of course has a \" or a \'   I want to get rid of the \ so I want to use the stripslash function.  Here is some samples from the php code, I just dont know where and how to use stripslash:

```
$item=$_POST['item'];
```

or should it be used on this part?

```
$savestring =  $carsearch . "\n" . $homesearch . "\n" . $next . "\n" . $item . "\n";
```

or maybe here:

```
fwrite($fp, $savestring);
```

I have left out most of the code on my php page to save space, but I just would really appreciate any help on where to use stripslash or if I should use another technique entirely.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have magic quotes turned on. Turn it off and the slashes will go away.

Comment: oh I have to go to the ini file and adjust the settings using my control panel.  I can take care of the rest.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have some custom code to add it, the data shouldn't have `/` characters prefixing the quotes.

It might have `\` if your version of PHP is not entirely up to date and you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on.

If that is the case, just turn magic quotes off. They do more harm then good.

If you can't (and if that is the case I recommend adding *that* problem instead), then the comments on the documentation I linked to above include some functions for fixing data that has been tainted by magic quotes.